# Operator == error

Tags: c++, class, operators, qvector

I have defined a class Point. I also have a class PointCollection : `class PointCollection: public QVector<Point>` Here when implementing some methods I get following error:

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Point' and 'const Point')

Here is the code part on which I have this error:

```
    Point PointCollection::getNearestPointToCentroid()
{
    float minDist = 0.0;
    int NearestPointToCentroidIndex = -1;
    while(!this->empty())
    {
        Point point;
        Point centroid;
        float dist = PointT.calculateEuclideanDist(point, centroid);
        if(this->indexOf(point) == 0)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            NearestPointToCentroidIndex = this->indexOf(point);
        }
        else
        {
            if(minDist > dist)
            {
                minDist = dist;
                NearestPointToCentroidIndex = this->indexOf(point);
            }
        }
    }
    return(this[NearestPointToCentroidIndex]);
}
```

Where: `Point centorid;float X;float Y;int Id;` are private variables of PointCollection class. In constructor I define :

```
PointCollection::PointCollection()
{
    //centorid = new Point;
    Id = PointT.GetId();
    X = PointT.GetX();
    Y = PointT.GetY();
}
```

And

```
float Point::calculateEuclideanDist(Point point_1, Point point_2)
{
    float x1 = point_1.x, y1 = point_1.y;
    float x2 = point_2.x, y2 = point_2.y;

    float dist = qSqrt(qPow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + qPow(y2 - y1, 2.0));


    return (dist);
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your `operator==` for `Point`?

Comment: Is `return(this[NearestPointToCentroidIndex]);` really what you meant to write?

Comment: @ juanchopanza: I am sorry but I didn't really catch what you mean. Point is just a class and the other class is following : class PointCollection: public QVector<Point>. The operator== is supposed to be the QVector's, if my understanding is right.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Yes, I need to have the index of the centroid.

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: @john: if(this->indexOf(point) == 0)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            NearestPointToCentroidIndex = this->indexOf(point);
        }
        else
        {
            if(minDist > dist)
            {
                minDist = dist;
                NearestPointToCentroidIndex = this->indexOf(point);
            }
        }

Comment: @Mike, that doesn't answer the question, are you sure you didn't mean `return (*this)[NearestPointToCentroidIndex];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in order to implement indexOf, QVector has to know how to compare Points for equality (otherwise how can it find the point in the vector). It uses operator== for this, but you haven't written operator== for class Point, so you get this error. Just write operator== for Point (and operator!= would be a good idea too).

```
bool operator==(const Point& x, const Point& y)
{
    // your code here
}

bool operator!=(const Point& x, const Point& y)
{
    return !(x == y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. bool Point::operator==()
{
    Point point = (Point)obj;
    if (this->x == point.x && this->y == point.y)
    {
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
} is this what you mean?

Comment: That would be wrong. I meant exactly what I wrote. There's no need to make operator== a class member, it's generally better if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you for valuable answer